# Updating to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server-2012, operating-system

I am currently running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition. A few weeks back I got the new server OS on a disk. I'm planning to upgrade the server by doing a full install, not an update. Well, because it's a server, I have a ton of settings done there. DHCP, DNS, IIS... tons of services and programs.

Is there a feature I can use to backup all the Windows Server settings (like those above) and then import them in the new server installation? Note the difference between the versions. 2008 to 2012.

Comment: Why are you upgrading?  What new 2012 features do you need?  Things would be far easier if you had new hardware for the new instance of Windows, and you brought the new one up and you migrated services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not any one tool to back up those settings and data for re-import onto a new OS; you would have to examine each application and do an export in the appropriate way.

DNS would be either the flat files for the zones if standard primary, or if it's AD integrated, you're doin' it wrong. The DNS server settings itself - I'm not sure how you could dump those, that might be in netsh.

DHCP can be dumped out with netsh.

IIS - use the native IIS 7 export functions for each site, I guess.

For everything else, there will be a different way of exporting and importing - or possibly even no way, for some weird LOB app that nobody knows anything about.

Since you have existing dependencies and configurations, can you explain why you are not doing an in-place upgrade?